# my click function isn't being pushed to the array like it should

Tags: arrays, onclick, push

I'm trying to check whether a click on a button is made by the computer or a human and then push that click index to an array. The computer click is made by a function that changes a boolean variable to trigger an if statement that then pushes the button to the array. When the function is called it is not being pushed to the simonClicked array, it is being pushed to the humanClicked array.

I tried pushing the index directly from the machineClick function but it still pushes to the humanClicked array.

```
function machineClick () {
    computerClick = true;
    buttons[Math.floor(Math.random() * buttons.length)].click();
    computerClick = false;
}

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
$(buttons[i]).click(function(index) {
    return function() {
        
        playSound(index); 
        this.classList.toggle("pressed")
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.classList.remove("pressed")
        }, 300);
        if (!computerClick) {
            simonClicked.push(index)
            targetClickCount++
        } else {
            humanClicked.push(index)
            clickCount++  
        };
         
        if (clickCount === targetClickCount) {
            nextLevel()

        }
        


    };
}(i));
```

}